# Is my rice pot still safe to use?

Tags: equipment

The bottom part metal of my rice pot has turned into darker colour as shown below. May i know if it is still *safe to use* and *what causes it to turn colour*? I think the pot is made up of anodised aluminium ? (Correct me if I am wrong)[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your rice pot looks like it has an uncoated aluminum insert.  Which also explains the discoloration: aluminum [easily discolors from hard (alkaline) water](https://iupilon.com/why-does-aluminum-cookware-turn-black/), or even from minerals from the rice itself.  These chemicals cause the surface of the aluminum to oxidize.

This discoloration is harmless and you can ignore it if you choose.  If it bothers you, it can be [removed with various household cleaners](https://homesteady.com/13421918/how-to-remove-hard-water-stains-from-anodized-aluminum).